# Cannot export site template

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to get site template and getting error:

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.xml
Get-PnPSiteTemplate : GetAccessTokenAsync() called without an ACS token generator. Specify in AuthenticationManager constructor the authentication parameters
At line:1 char:1

- Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.xml
- CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPSiteTemplate], ArgumentException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.GetSiteTemplate

Version:
pnp.powershell 1.6.0

Comment: I am literally getting the exact same error and can't pin down why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with PnP.PowerShell 1.6.0. I was using Connect-PnPOnline command with -UseWebLogin flag because my account had multi factor authentication turned on.

My solution was to disable MFA for my user and connect without the "-UseWebLogin" flag. Then Get-PnPSiteTemplate command worked without any issues.

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I'll use this workaround for now :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after quite some time invested in troubleshooting, I've figured out that the export gets interrupted once it iterates over a list. It is not related to the site you're trying to export because it happened also on other, newly created sites.

It turned out that the problem was that the PNP Module requires Admin Consent since it can manipulate almost all components of O365.

Solution: Connect to the site with the following command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -interactive -URL "Your Site Url"
```

Provide admin consent to PnP and then try to export the site template with:

```
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "File Location" # Use handlers and other params if needed
```

If the prompt window doesn't show up, run the following command first:

```
register-pnpmanagementshellaccess # See notes before running this cmdlet
```

**Note**: Admin consent requires additional permissions and `SharePoint Admin` role is not enough! So either ask a `Global Admin` to consent for you or ask for additional AD permissions. If I'm not mistaken `Application Administrator` role should be the right choice.

Comment: IIUC I must use the Interactive flag when opening the connection in order for "Get-PnPSiteTemplate" to work properly (my task is to make a full, deep clone of the site). The site I want to download from is not under my control. I have worked with a Global admin to that site and they swear that they have given me sufficient rights, yet I get the permission error 401. The documentation at https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/connecting.html is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have worked for me.

```
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -out template.xml -ExcludeHandlers Lists,ApplicationLifecycleManagement
```

It seems the lists and ALM sections need an ACS token generator and that fails with UseWebLogin.

This is what I got on version 1.7.10, but I have used 1.7.0 and 1.5.0 and seen the same issues. I don't know if the older versions have more problematic modules.

Method: I found this resolution by running `Set-PnPTraceLog -on -logfile log.txt -Level Debug` and `Set-PnPTraceLog -off`, then reviewing log file to see which module failed.

I may use the `Export-PnPListToSiteTemplate` and see how that goes in getting list XML for the template file.

Comment: major lifesaver!